# Android ICS status bar not hiding on click of notification

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-notifications

I am launching activity from notification using

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(context, TestActivity.class);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
PendingIntent launcher = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.test_launch_btn, launcher);
```

If activity is not visible and I click on notification it is working fine. The problem is that in `ICS` if activity is already visible and I click from notification status bar does not slide up on click of notification whereas in `Jellybean` status bar slide up on click. 
Status bar is not collapsing on click in notification in ICS.
What can be done to hide status bar on click of notification. I am using S3 running 4.0.4.

Comment: In case of ICS I think it is not calling collapse method of StatusBarManager class. Anyone know when it is called by framework.

Comment: In log I see that system try to launch activity 06-28 13:21:49.522: I/ActivityManager(533): START {act=android.intent.action.VIEW flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.test/.TestActivity 
bnds=[0,432][172,604]} from pid -1. But it is not launched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, Honeycomb and ICS don't automatically close the notification panel when a button inside is clicked to launch an Activity. (At the time we didn't have a way to tell which of your notification's buttons were going to launch an Activity, nor could we intercept that click appropriately. It wouldn't have made sense to close the panel on *any* click, because it would have made things like music controllers really unpleasant.)

Here's what you can do: On HC+ICS, once your Activity has been started this way, you can broadcast [`Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS) to explicitly close the notification panel. Only do this on pre-Jelly Bean devices, and only if your activity has been started in response to your own notification's PendingIntent.

Note that this is still the only way to close the panel on Jelly Bean if your notification's buttons use broadcast intents instead of starting activities.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am closing status bar by calling method through reflection for ICS devices.
    Object service  = getSystemService("statusbar");
    Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
    Method collapse = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapse");
             collapse.setAccessible(true);
             collapse.invoke(service);

Comment: Just use the broadcast; you won't need to rely on reflection against methods that aren't checked by CTS and therefore are not guaranteed to be available on all Android devices.